# Angular JS - calculation

Tags: angularjs

My calculation works well for value with 3 digits and below.
For example, item_amt = 250 + 250 will give output 500.
But, when it comes to 4 digits and above, it will give single digit only.
For example, item_amt = 2500 + 2500 will give output 1.

HTML:

```
      <ion-card *ngFor = "let c of cart" class="item-card">
        <ion-row float="right">
          <ion-col size="2" offset="5">
            <ion-button color="medium" fill="clear" (click)="removeCartItem(c)" class="btn-remove-item">
              <ion-icon name="close-circle" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row><ion-label text-wrap>{{c.name}}</ion-label></ion-row><br/>
        <ion-row>ITEM PRICE : <ion-label text-wrap>{{c.item_amount}}</ion-label></ion-row><br/>
        <ion-row text-wrap>
          QUANTITY :
          <ion-item>
            <ion-button color="medium" fill="clear" (click)="decreaseCartItem(c)">
              <ion-icon name="remove-circle" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
            <div class="quantity-input">{{c.quantity}}</div>
            <ion-button color="medium" fill="clear" (click)="increaseCartItem(c)">
              <ion-icon name="add-circle" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-card>
```

Below is the Controller:

```
  increaseCartItem(product) {
    this.cart.addProduct(product);
  }
```

Below is my cart calculation.

```
  addProduct(product) {
    let added = false;
    for (let p of this.cart) {
      if (p.product_id === product.product_id) {
        //console.log('P'+p.item_amount);
        //console.log(product.price);
        p.item_amount = parseInt(p.item_amount) + parseInt(product.price);
        product.quantity += 1;
        product.amount += 1;
        added = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!added) {
      product.amount = 1;
      this.cart.push(product);
    }
    this.cartItemCount.next(this.cartItemCount.value + 1);
  }
```

I'm new to Angular JS. Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Create working snippet

Comment: use debugger and console.log() it will help you Most Probably your code i.e. : `if (!added) { product.amount = 1; this.cart.push(product); }` is getting fire in an unwanted condition